# Node Server side does not get data from this.http.delete

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have been learning services for angular 2 and i am trying to send information using this.http.delete method as follows

**posts.component.ts FILE**

```
userdeletion(email){

    let user = {
      email: email,
    };

    this.postsService.deletePosts(user).subscribe(
      posts => {
        return true;
      },
      error => {
        console.error("Error deleting user!");
      }
    )
  }
```

**posts.service.ts FILE**

```
  deletePosts(deleteUser) {
    return this.http.delete('/api/posts/', deleteUser)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

when i go to my server side, i do not get any data. Can someone explain me, what i am doing wrong in my service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sending `user` object inside `body` options of `RequestOptions` object in second parameter of `http.delete`

```
deletePosts(deleteUser) {
    return this.http.delete('/api/posts/', new RequestOptions({
         body: deleteUser
      }))
     .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. would i have to use RequestOptions for `this.http.put`?

Comment: @cacev000 yes you have to, but method would be `patch`/`put` method

Answer (score 0):

"deleteUser" is an object and you need to pass it with JSON.stringify:

```
deletePosts(deleteUser) {
    return this.http.delete('/api/posts/', JSON.stringify(deleteUser))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```